# Ubuntu 12.04 ' sudo apt-get update ' returns following :

Tags: 12.04

```
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 .
 'sudo apt-get update' 
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise Release.gpg
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-backports Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise Release
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates Release
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security Release
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports Release
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed Release
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restrictedTranslationIndex           
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Err http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-backports/main Sources 
  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-backports/restricted Sources
  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-backports/universe Sources
  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages
  504  Connect to archive.canonical.com:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-backports/multiverse Sources
  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe TranslationIndex
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restricted Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted Sources
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Err http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi precise-proposed/universe Translation-en
/main/source/Sources  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/restricted/source/Sources  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/universe/source/Sources  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  504  Connect to fi.archive.ubuntu.com:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to archive.canonical.com:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/universe/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/main/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/multiverse/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/restricted/source/Sources  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/universe/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  504  Connect to mirrors.nic.funet.fi:80 failed: Connection refused

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

ping mirrors.nic.funet.fi
PING mirrors.nic.funet.fi (193.166.3.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
sudo lshw | grep
           *-network
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
sudo lshw | grep wireless
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.2.0-60-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.100.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Comment: The mirror could have been down. Please try `sudo apt-get update` again and check if it's working now. If it doesn't, could you post the output of `ping mirrors.nic.funet.fi`?

Comment: Switch to a different mirror in software and. Updates.

Comment: PING mirrors.nic.funet.fi (193.166.3.5) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a few entries that are for `maverick`, which is no longer supported or available. You might want to take those out.

Answer (score 0):

As  Louis Matthijssen surmised, the server may be down. Trying again may resolve the issue. If not open Ubuntu Software Center Choose Edit, Software Sources and there's a setting for "download from" where you can choose a different mirror and try again.

Comment: Tried 'Select best server' and for a moment downloading from an Estonian server worked but suddenly it failed : check internet connection .

Comment: Please provide the output of:                                   sudo lshw

Comment: 'the output of: sudo lshw' could'nt be added by editing because of character limit and as the noob I am ...will be back tomorrow ,Thanks

Comment: @user274687 Please provide the output of:   sudo lshw | grep net   as well as the output of:                   sudo lshw | grep wireless